# What is the correct way to filter and calculate a number from array of object

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular-filters

In angularjs, how to loop through the arrays and get a value from a respected label and count with each other and return the value?

example i have an array like this:

```
"contractorsList": [
            {
              "name": "KP/A995/29",
              "percent": 78
            },
            {
              "name": "KP/A574/69",
              "percent": 33
            },
            {
              "name": "KP/A520/30",
              "percent": 38
            },
            {
              "name": "KP/A787/57",
              "percent": 35
            },
            {
              "name": "KP/A850/75",
              "percent": 49
            },
            {
              "name": "KP/A374/17",
              "percent": 47
            },
            {
              "name": "KP/A962/40",
              "percent": 33
            }
          ]
```

here there is a field as `percent`, i would like to iterate across the objects and need to get the total value of the percent. ( adding each percent to gather)

what is the correct way to do this in `angular.js`

i tried like this, but i didn't get any value:

```
scope.totalContracts = $filter('filter')( contractorsList, {percent:!null});

//i assumed to get the total values as array, so that i can add.
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var total = contractorsList.reduce(function(result, item) {
  return result + item.percent;
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
var val=0;
angular.forEach(contractorsList, function(value, key) {
    if(value.name === "KP/A995/29"){
       val += value.percent;
    }
}, contractorsList);
```

I hope this help.

Detailed Explanation:
It is simple, having a global variable 'val' with value 0, and adding the percent of each iterated object, in the given 'contratorsList'(i.e. array of objects), while iterating through it using angularJs function forEach. Please check for forEach of angular in documentation link: docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach Also the last parameter can be omitted as it is just a context of the iterator function. Hope this clears your doubts!! –

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation for your answer?

Comment: It is simple, having a global variable 'val' with value 0, and adding the percent of each iterated object, in the given 'contratorsList'(i.e. array of objects), while iterating through it using angularJs function forEach. Please check for forEach of angular in documentation link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Also the last parameter can be omitted as it is just a context of the iterator function.

Hope this clears your doubts!!

Comment: Yes, it helps. Could you please move your explanation to the question? It would be best if you could refrase your answer with the explanation.